# Autoplay the text-to-speech response on mobile browser after I receive message from the server

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I have this web application where I exchange messages with an AI model. Every time I want to say the response out loud when I receive a new one. In the browser this works fine, but it seems my solution doesn't work on mobile browsers because they don't allow autoplay.

Anyone got a crafty solution to this? It's a vital part of the experience of my app and I don't know how to proceed. I do not want the user to have to click a play button every time they receive a response. I want the sound to be played automatically.

```
function playAudio(audioUrl: any) {
  fetch(audioUrl)
      .then(response => response.arrayBuffer())
      .then(arrayBuffer => audioContext.decodeAudioData(arrayBuffer))
      .then(audioBuffer => {
          const source = audioContext.createBufferSource();
          source.buffer = audioBuffer;
          source.connect(audioContext.destination);
          source.start();
      })
      .catch(error => console.error(error));
}
```

[image]

Comment: I just tested this code on a computer and a mobile device. For automatic playback, you must perform a custom action on the page at least once. And in this regard it is the same on both devices. In addition, an error appears - invalid character "**:**" in line 1.

Comment: The fact that the browser has [autoplay policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Autoplay_guide#the_autoplay_permissions_policy) is the major drawback you have. See [using the Web Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API/Using_Web_Audio_API) to understand how to work around these.

Comment: It is always a matter of getting the user to [allow autoplay first time then subsequent attempts will get it working.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Autoplay_guide#autoplay_availability)

Comment: Thanks guys, I will do further research

Comment: @Опан the invalid character is probably because you're running it into JS file while it is Typescript